# How to get expectation (E-value) for a dataset?

Tags: r, extreme-value

For an examination, scores for 10 students (all from class 4B) were obtained.  I want to convert each score to E-value.

If I understand correctly, to calculate E-value I have to determine an unrelated population first, so, I also got scores for 30 students in Class 4A.

For discussion, I have generated two datasets here:

```
class4B <- c (0, 10, 20, 30, 50, 40, 70, 80, 90, 99)
class4A <- c(1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 90, 12, 14, 15, 44, 66,  88, 67, 78, 90, 45, 
             67, 99, 100, 12, 45, 56, 100, 23, 45, 29)
```

- Would you mind to let me know how to get the TEN E-values for each students in Class4B with R?
- Should we consider the population in class4A?
- Is it a statistically sound approach to get E-value based on an unrelated population or so called "random population"?

Comment: What is an "e-value"?  This is not a standard term AFAIK.  Could you supply a reference?

Answer (score 2):

Your title uses the word "expectation" with "E-value" in parenthesis.   So, I'm assuming that your E-value is the expected value.....the mean.

```
class4B <- c (0, 10, 20, 30, 50, 40, 70, 80, 90, 99)

mean(class4B)
```

The above mean(class4B) statement returns 48.9

```
class4A <- c(1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 90, 12, 14, 15, 44, 66, 88, 67, 78, 90, 45, 67, 99, 100, 12, 45, 56, 100, 23, 45, 29)

mean(class4A)
```

The above mean(class4A) statement returns 40.53333

I don't understand what you want when you asked: "...Would you mind to let me know how to get the TEN E-values for each students in Class4B with R?...".   Take a look at:

```
?scale

scale(class4B)
```

From your second question: "....Should we consider the population in class4A? Is it a statistically sound approach to get E-value based on an unrelated population or so called "random population"?...."

If you want to combine class4A and class4B to get the mean or scale, try:

```
mean(c(class4B, class4A))

scale(c(class4B, class4A))
```